# ng-if inside ng-repeat in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ng-if

I am presenting a separate div based on if condition inside ng-repeat. but it throws an error saying " **Syntax Error: Token '<' not a primary expression at column 32 of the expression [widget.Type == 'Bar'>".**
How can i fix it?

here is my code,

**HTML:**

```
  <div   id="main"  class="drop-container" ng-click="addEvent($event)" droppable>
    <div ng-controller="CustomWidgetCtrl"  style="margin: 20px; top: 50px; left: 80px; height: 300px; width: 500px; " ng-repeat="widget in dashboard.widgets" ng-style="{ 'left':widget.sizeX, 'top':widget.sizeY }"
    data-identifier="{{widget.id}}">
    <div class="box" >
        <div class="box-header" >
        <h3>{{ widget.name }}</h3>
    <div class="box-header-btns pull-right">
    <a title="settings" ng-click="openSettings(widget)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></i></a>
    <a title="Remove widget" ng-click="remove(widget)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></a>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div ng-if="widget.Type == 'Bar'>
      <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">  <div  data-ac-chart="'Bar'"  data-ac-data="data" data-ac-config="config"  class="chart">
      </div>
    </body>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: there should be an extra quote after 'Bar' in ng-if condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is an syntax error, you are missing closing double quotation mark in ng-if so it is reaching next html tag

```
<div ng-if="widget.Type == 'Bar'">
```